# Redirect one html page to another in pop up using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am using angularjs. I need to open one html page from another in a pop up/modal. Actually needs a common html page with script(angular controller), which is open from different multiple view page as a modal/pop up, and also can do CRUD in modal.

```
<div><button data-ng-click="openModal()">Click</button></div>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.openModal = function(){  // Do something to open another html view page in a modal    }
```

Also i need some information send from current UI to modal UI as a parameter.

Comment: You mean you want to open model, correct?

Comment: I want to open modal, and do crud operation also. Like create list, input text value then Save, Delete from modal.

Answer (score 3):

```
var app = angular.module('someapp');
$scope.openModal = function(){
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
        controller: 'someconroller',
        resolve: {
            argumentToSend: function () {
                return 'sample-text';
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (returnedItem) {
        console.log(returnedItem);
    }, function () {
    })
};

app.controller('someconroller', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'argumentToSend', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, argumentToSend) {
    console.log(argumentToSend);
    //You can call your services,apis for crud operations here
    $scope.exit = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close(returnedItem);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   $scope.openModal = function(){ 
    $scope.inserted = {
                    //data which you want to display on modal
                };

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: path to your html,
            scope: $scope,
            size: "Modelwidth",
            controller: //controller name,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    $scope.inserted
                }
            }
        });
  }
```